# Batch job submission failed: Requested node configuration is not available SLURM

Tags: bash, hpc, slurm

I am using trying to submit a bash job script with slurm. The following is contained in my bash script:

```
#SBATCH --partition=normal
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=8
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=2
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:v100d32q:1
#SBATCH --mem=12000
#SBATCH --time=0-01:00:00
```

I cannot seem to understand why am I getting the following error:

```
sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Requested node configuration is not available
```

I know this question is asked before. But cannot seem to find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the error by removing the following:

```
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:v100d32q:1
```

Happy computing!